# Why is a pickled SQLAlchemy model object smaller than its pickled `__dict__`?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The same attributes stored in `__dict__` are needed to restore the object, right?

Comment: Pickling the dict needs to pickle all the attribute names, too.

Answer (score 1):

I think a SQLAlchemy RowProxy uses _row, a tuple, to store the value.  It doesn't have a __dict__, so no storage overhead of a _dict__ per row.  Its _parent object has fields which store the column names to index pos in tuple lookup.  Pretty common thing to do if you are trying to cut on down sql fetching result sizes - the column list is always the same for each row of the same select, so you rely on a common parent to keep track of which index of the tuple holds which column rather than having your own per-row __dict__.

Additional advantage is that, at the db lib connect level, sql cursors return (always?) their values in tuples, so you have little processing overhead.  But a straight sql fetch is just that, a cursor descr & a bunch of disconnected rows with tuples in them - SQLALchemy bridges that and allows to use column names.

Now, as to how the unpickling process goes, you'd have to look at the actual implementation.